# ITextSharp ignores my HTML code style and css

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, itext

First of all use Dreamweaver CC to create an HTML page with images inside to simulate a PDF page where you can rename some variables that will be presented in the final PDF file.
I have created some divs and I have given them size and style so that it looks as much as possible to what is required in design

Im using this code to export a pdf file called test.pdf with iTextSharp

```
            Byte[] bytes;`var example_html = "<!doctype html><html><head><meta charset =\"utf-8\" ></ head >< body >< div style=\"width: 1191px; height: 1688px;\" ><img src = \"1.png\" width=\"100%\"/><div style = \"float:left;\" >< img src=\"2.png\" /></div><div style = \"overflow:auto\" >< p style=\"font-size: 50px; text-align: right;\">TOLKNINGSRAPPORT</p><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><p style = \"font-size: 20px; text-align: right;\" > Förslag för</p><p style = \"font-size: 30px; text-align: right; color:#7C0002\" ><strong> NAME </strong></p><p style=\"font-size: 20px; text-align: right;\">date</p>   <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><p style = \"font-size: 80px; text-align: right;\">ASSESSIO\"</p></ div ></ div ></ body ></ html >";
```

`

```
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var doc = new Document())
            {
                using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms))
                {
                    doc.Open();
                    using (var htmlWorker = new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker(doc))
                    {
                        using (var sr = new StringReader(example_html))
                        {
                            htmlWorker.Parse(sr);
                        }
                    }
                    doc.Close();
                }
            }
            bytes = ms.ToArray();
        }
        var testFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "test.pdf");
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(testFile, bytes);
```

My html code style is like this picture:[What i want my pdf look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m55r3.png)

But the pdf ignores the style and the final result looks like this:
[PDF Style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gI4Ok.png)

Anyone knows how to solve this.. or make the pdf look exactly like HTML looks like in browsers?

Comment: You ate using `HTMLWorker`. **Of course, all your styling is lost!!!** You should use either iText's XML Worker (if you stick to the old iTextSharp 5) or the pdfHTML add-on (if you upgrade to iText 7 for .Net). If I were you, I'd upgrade.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Im new using iTextSharp and i dont understand it at all. Im going To try with xmlworker

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Im using XMLWorker now but it export a pdf without content

Comment: Update your question with your new code

Comment: Please also share your html and dependent resources.